# Creating a simple remote model using Django-ROA

Tags: python, django, django-models

I recently came across [`django-roa`](https://bitbucket.org/david/django-roa/wiki/Home) and figured it would be a great fit for a project I'm working on. Unfortunately, I'm having the hardest time with their basic example. I have set up a basic django project, so I'm positive that the problem has nothing to do with the initial setup.

I have a simple model:

```
from django.db import models
from django_roa import Model

class RemoteModel(Model):
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    @staticmethod
    def get_resource_url_list():
        return u'http://my-restful-url/path/resource'
```

...and here are the relevant portions of my `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django_roa',
    'myapps',
    # ... other default apps ...
)

# ROA Stuff
ROA_MODELS = True
ROA_FORMAT = 'json'
ROA_DJANGO_ERRORS = True
ROA_HEADERS = {
    'ApiKey': 'apikey'
}
```

However, when I go to test out this example, this happens...

```
>>> from myapps.models import RemoteModel
>>> RemoteModel.objects.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'objects'
>>> type(RemoteModel)
<type 'NoneType'>
```

Have I missed something? From what I can see, the setup is almost identical to the provided [twitter example app](http://code.larlet.fr/django-roa/src/f9883ce2d1a02e7bc1f2c49a43d488d9b7e98686/examples/twitter_roa/models.py?at=default).

*How do I set up a simple remote model using Django-ROA?*

**EDIT:**
Here are the packages installed:

```
Django==1.4.1
django-roa==1.7
http-parser==0.8.3
restkit==4.2.2
socketpool==0.5.3
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of this writing, the above example *should work*. The problem is the `django-roa` code. The listed package (1.7) doesn't support beyond Django 1.2.

There has been work in [this pull request](https://bitbucket.org/xordoquy/django-roa/pull-request/1/upgrade-to-work-with-django-15/diff) to get `django-roa` working in Django 1.5, but to get things working for 1.4 or 1.3, you'll need to make the following changes as described in that pull request:

> Yeah, it just requires to remove [the] `attached_to` parameter from [the] `add_to_class` method call in order to support django 1.4 and remove the `only_installed` parameter from `get_model` function call in order to support django 1.3, after catching `TypeError`. Both [changes are] in `db/models.py`.